# UICollectionView doesn't fill data from right to left in RTL

Tags: ios, right-to-left, collectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` and want to display cells horizontally, e.g.

**In English**, it should display:
**| cellA | cellB | cellC |**

**In Arabic**, it should display:
**[ cellC | cellB | cellA |**

For RTL, the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` works fine by default for me if every cell has the same size. However, if I implement `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` and set different widths for each cell, the **CollectionView** becomes:

| cellA | cellB | cellC |

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You need to implement your own `UICollectionViewLayout` to handle that

Comment: @ReinierMelian I may need to use your suggestion to solve it.

Comment: Iam working in an answer now, as soon as I have something i will post it

Comment: Your cells height will be fixed? or both width and height are variable?

Comment: @ReinierMelian Only width is variable.

Comment: Check if this is what you need https://imgur.com/a/FgqS0Bc?

Comment: @ReinierMelian Yes. Did you write your own UICollectionViewLayout?

Comment: Check my answer and let me know about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own `UICollectionViewLayout`, as I said in my comment, we will start backwards, first you need to add this lines on your `ViewController` `viewDidLoad` method

```
let semanticLayout = SemanticLayout()
semanticLayout.delegate = self
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = semanticLayout
```

this is the delegate that you need to implement

```
extension ViewController: SemanticLayoutDelegate{
    func semanticDisposition() -> SemanticDisposition {
        return SemanticDisposition.rigthToLeft
    }   
}
```

using your ViewController name instead of ViewController ofc

And here you have the `SemanticLayout` class, check that is **fully customizable** you can define if your `UICollectionView` will be RTL or LTR with delegate method `semanticDisposition`

```
import UIKit


protocol SemanticLayoutDelegate: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func semanticDisposition() -> SemanticDisposition
}

enum SemanticDisposition {
    case leftToRigth
    case rigthToLeft
}

class SemanticLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

    weak var delegate: SemanticLayoutDelegate!

    fileprivate var cellPadding: CGFloat = 10

    fileprivate var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    fileprivate var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0
    private var rowsWidth : [CGFloat] = [0]
    private var avaiableSpaces : [(Int,CGFloat)] = []
    private var currentRow : Int = 0
    private var rowHeigths : CGFloat = -1.0

    fileprivate var contentWidth: CGFloat {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return 0
        }
        let insets = collectionView.contentInset
        return collectionView.bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
    }

    private func availableWidthForRow(index:Int) -> CGFloat {
        let ocuppedWidth = self.rowsWidth[index]
        return self.contentWidth - ocuppedWidth
    }

    private func canAddCellAtRow(rowIndex:Int,size:CGSize) ->Bool
    {
        if(availableWidthForRow(index: rowIndex) >= size.width) {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
    }

    override func prepare() {
        // Check if cache is empty
        guard cache.isEmpty == true, let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return
        }

        for item in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {

            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)

            let viewSize: CGSize = delegate.collectionView!(collectionView, layout: self, sizeForItemAt: indexPath)
            if(self.rowHeigths < 0) {
                self.rowHeigths = viewSize.height
            }

            let width = viewSize.width
            let height = viewSize.height

            var xOffset = self.rowsWidth[self.currentRow]
            if(self.canAddCellAtRow(rowIndex: self.currentRow, size: viewSize)) {

                if(self.delegate.semanticDisposition() == .rigthToLeft) {
                    xOffset = (contentWidth - self.rowsWidth[self.currentRow]) - width
                }

            } else {
                self.currentRow += 1
                self.rowsWidth.append(0.0)
                xOffset = self.rowsWidth[self.currentRow]
                if(self.delegate.semanticDisposition() == .rigthToLeft) {
                    xOffset = (contentWidth - self.rowsWidth[self.currentRow]) - width
                }

            }

            let yOffset = CGFloat(self.currentRow) * self.rowHeigths

            let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset, y: yOffset, width: width, height: height)
            let insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: cellPadding, dy: cellPadding)

            let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
            attributes.frame = insetFrame
            cache.append(attributes)

            contentHeight = max(contentHeight, frame.maxY)

            self.rowsWidth[self.currentRow]  += width
        }
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        var visibleLayoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        // Loop through the cache and look for items in the rect
        for attributes in cache {
            if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
                visibleLayoutAttributes.append(attributes)
            }
        }
        return visibleLayoutAttributes
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return cache[indexPath.item]
    }
}
```

**Result**
**RTL**

[image: RTL]
**LTR**
[image: LTR]

Answer (score 6):

```
class RTLSupportedCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override var flipsHorizontallyInOppositeLayoutDirection: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

you can use this flow layout. it is only needed when the item size returned is not same for all the cells.

Answer (score 0):

This class is working for me to display collection view from left to right with different sizes of cells.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static const char kBundleKey = 0;

@interface BundleEx : NSBundle

@end

@implementation BundleEx

- (NSString *)localizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value table:(NSString *)tableName
{
    NSBundle *bundle = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &kBundleKey);
    if (bundle) {
        return [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:value table:tableName];
    }
    else {
        return [super localizedStringForKey:key value:value table:tableName];
    }
}

@end

@implementation NSBundle (Language)

+ (void)setLanguage:(NSString *)language
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        object_setClass([NSBundle mainBundle], [BundleEx class]);
    });
    if (isCurrentLanguageRTL) {
        if ([[[UIView alloc] init] respondsToSelector:@selector(setSemanticContentAttribute:)]) {
            [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
            [[UITableView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
        }
    }else {
        //FOR LTR
        if ([[[UIView alloc] init] respondsToSelector:@selector(setSemanticContentAttribute:)]) {
            [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
            [[UITableView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
        }
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    id value = language ? [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:language ofType:@"lproj"]] : nil;
    objc_setAssociatedObject([NSBundle mainBundle], &kBundleKey, value, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

@end
```

Hope this help. let me know if further help needed.