# swift - right to left horizontal collection view in displayed incorrectly from left to right

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, right-to-left

I'm displaying a horizontal collection view from right to left and encountering a problem that when displaying the elements, they are displayed from the end (left to right instead):

- In the run schema options, the app language is set as right to left pseudo language
- If I'm adding the items when starting the app before instead of adding them after and calling reloadData, the problem doesn't occur
- Sample project and screenshots are attached

One solution proposed was adding the code below that worked but required me to reverse the order to add the items. I would like to know if there's a better way to do it and also within the API instead of using an overriding extension

```
extension UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

open override var flipsHorizontallyInOppositeLayoutDirection: Bool {
    return true
}
```

}

[sample project](https://github.com/guylis/swift_test/tree/master/horizontalCollectionbViewTest)

help would be appreciated

code:

```
import UIKit

class HorizontalScrollTestViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource , CellDelegate{


    var items = [String]()

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ReusableCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell

    cell.category.setTitle(items[indexPath.row] , for: UIControl.State.normal)
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell

}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "resourcesQueue", qos: .background)
    dispatchQueue.async {
        self.addItems()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }

    }
    collectionView.dataSource = self

    collectionView?.register(UINib(nibName: "CategoryCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ReusableCell")


}

func buttonPressed(_ cell: UICollectionViewCell) {
    if  let row = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)?.row {
        print(items[row])
    }
}


func addItems() {
    self.items.append("test 10")
    self.items.append("test 9")
    self.items.append("test 8")
    self.items.append("test 7")
    self.items.append("test 6")
    self.items.append("test 5")
    self.items.append("test 4")
    self.items.append("test 3")
    self.items.append("test 2")
    self.items.append("test 1")



 }
}
```

**example when adding the items after the app started and using reloadData:**
[image: example when adding the items after the app started and using reloadData]

**expected behavior**

[image: expected behavior]

Comment: Please share the code snippets of how you're populating the collection view instead of sharing the whole project

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/54087393/2767774

Comment: jst let me know when u add new element like say "Test11" then where the collection should scroll.?? extreme right (test1 ) or  extreme left (test11)

Comment: @S1LENTWARRIOR code snippet added

Comment: @dRAGONAIR, thanks, see my updated comment

Comment: @SaifanNadaf when adding test11, as the app is from right to left, I would like it to be added to the left at the end, however the scrolling should always start at the beginning from the right at test1

Comment: If scrolling is the issue, set `collectionView.contentOffset.y = collectionView.contentSize.width - collectionView.frame.width` after the collectionView is populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you just flip your `collectionView` and `collectionViewCell` horizontally. this will solve your issue.

With this you can flip your collectionView horizontally. so that your collectionView starts from right. your first element will be at right and last element will be at left.

```
collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
```

OR

```
collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(a: -1.0, b: 0.0, c: 0.0, d: 1.0, tx: 0.0, ty: 0.0)
```

Similarly you have to flip each `collectionViewCell` also using

```
cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
```

OR

```
cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(a: -1.0, b: 0.0, c: 0.0, d: 1.0, tx: 0.0, ty: 0.0)
```

and add element in array in following order

```
func addItems() {
        self.items.append("test 1")
        self.items.append("test 2")
        self.items.append("test 3")
        self.items.append("test 4")
        self.items.append("test 5")
        self.items.append("test 6")
        self.items.append("test 7")
        self.items.append("test 8")
        self.items.append("test 9")
        self.items.append("test 10")
    }
```

Download updated project from [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v9d-ALSGuP9V4bqpSIg_WYEQEkfJP_fR/view?usp=sharing)